# end-weight principle

Tags: word-order

a) To check / b) checking the weather before you go outside in this country is important.
[told to a tourist]

How normal is this sentence to you -- slightly unidiomatic or very much so?

I'm asking this because I want to know if this is a good sentence to demonstrate the importance of end-weight principle in English. But to me the b variant doesn't sound so bad. I guess to me it sounds slightly worse than the sentence "it is important to check the weather...)

Comment: ***To check** the weather before you go out is a good idea* isn't idiomatically valid. Either resequence to *It's a good idea **to check** the weather before you go out* or use the gerund form ***Checking** the weather before you go out is a good idea.*

Answer (score 0):

[Thomson Rivers University](https://inside.tru.ca/2016/11/10/gerunds-and-infinitives/) explains the use of gerund-participles and infinitives.

Gerund-participles can be used

> [t]o **replace the subject** or object of a sentence:

> [1] **Jumping** off a cliff is dangerous, but a real thrill.

Infinitives can be used "after many adjectives":

> [2] It is **hard to make** dinner this late.

> I find it **difficult to describe** my feelings about writing research essays.

Hence we can apply [1], or [2], which involves the **anticipatory it**, in the form "it BE ADJECTIVE to VERB":

> b. **Checking the weather** before you go outside in this country is important.

> **It is important to check** the weather ...